# Download complete playlist with specific format in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to download complete playlist from YouTube with youtube-dl but I am not able to specify the format of the video I.e webm or HD etc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming ?

Comment: Necessity is root cause for programming

Answer (score 1):

1. use [this link](http://youtubemultidownloader.com/playlist.html) to get the download ink sequence for all the videos.
2. Copy all the links and save it to text file.
3. Use linux download client like uget. In that select "new batch download"
4. in the source select "import from text file" . choose the file where you save all the download sequence links.
5. start your download :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give all the available formats

```
youtube-dl -F linkofvideo
```

For Download

```
youtube-dl -f formatcode linkofvideo
```

format code is 22,17 given by first query

And in order to download complete video/playlist just write down

```
youtube-dl -f 22 linkofvideo
```